# Lower cased properties in Java

Tags: java, properties, jboss

Do anyone know if it is possible to have lower case letters in a property file in Java?
Currently when I have Example:

```
My_Conf=1234567
```

I get, when checking the property

```
My_Conf=null
```

in the code.

The code is suppose to be ran in Jboss servlet engine.

Best regards

Comment: Please try to reproduce this in a short but *complete* console application. I suspect you're not actually loading the properties file you think you're loading.

Comment: I can se that the file is loaded correctly, cause if I edit it to uppercase it works and I can see the change.
Also, Iäm adding properties in the code itself, with the same result.

Comment: Then your code relies on custom logic that retrieves the property using `.toUpperCase`.

Comment: Please post more code if u want help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible to have lower case characters in a `.properties` file. The problem might be that your code doesn't load the file.

For more information, have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29

Answer (score 0):

Try this for debugging purpose:

```
    String filename = "example.properties";
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    BufferedInputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        try {
            properties.load(stream);
            String prop = properties.getProperty("My_Conf");
            System.out.println(prop);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }finally{
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
```